# A bad casting to Generics parameter type does not throw ClassCastException in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

So, I have rather esoteric question.  I'm trying to create a somewhat generic, but typed property collection system.  It's reliant on a core assumption that seems to be erroneous.  The code illustrates the issue:

```
import java.lang.Integer;

public class Test {
    private static Object mObj = new String("This should print");

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
    String s = Test.<String>get();
    System.out.println(s);

        try {
        // actual ClassCastException reported HERE
        int i = Test.<Integer>get();
    } catch ( ClassCastException e ) {
        System.out.println("Why isn't the exception caught earlier?");
        }

        int i2 = getInt();
    }

    public static <T> T get() {
    T thing = null;
    try {
        // Expected ClassCastException here
        thing = (T)mObj;
    } catch ( ClassCastException e ) {
        System.out.println("This will *not* be printed");
    }
    return thing;
    }

    // This added in the edit
    public static Integer getInt() {
    return (Integer)mObj;
    }
}
```

After compiling and running the output is

```
This should print
Why isn't the exception caught earlier?
```

In the static method "get", I'm attempting to cast to the generic parameter type T.  The underlying member (mObj) is of String type.  In the first invocation, the Generic parameter is of compatible type, so the app prints the string appropriately.

In the second invocation, the Generic parameter is of type Integer.  Thus, the cast in the get method should fail.  And I would hope it would throw a ClassCastException (printing the statement "This will *not* be printed".)  But this isn't what happens.

Instead, the casting exception is thrown *after* the get method returns when the returned value is attempted to be assigned to the variable "i".  Here's the question:

What is the explanation for this delayed casting error?

**   EDIT   **
For the sake of fun and completeness, I added a non-generic getInt method to illustrate the response I was hoping to get.  Amazing what happens when the compiler knows type.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  I guess I'm just too C++ oriented.  I want to think about Java Generics as I do C++ templates -- a compile-time process.  So, thank you all for giving a me a better insight into Java generics.  I'll just have to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the cast in the `get` method (which should generate a compiler warning) is an unchecked cast. The compiler does not know what `T` is when you call `thing = (T) mObj;` so it cannot know if the cast should not compile.

After compilation, and due to type erasure, the bytecode generated invokes the method `get` which returns an `Object` (`T` is erased and replaced with `Object`) and the cast is simply translated to:

```
Object thing = null;
try {
    thing = mObj;
```

The check is being done *after* the result is returned from the `get` method, i.e. `int i = Test.<Integer> get();` is equivalent to:

```
Object o = Test.get();
int i = ((Integer) o).intValue();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  On the whole, I like it.  I have a small technical quibble.  You say the cast in the get method is "unchecked".  Generally, the syntax "(Type) obj" is a checked cast.  Does Java make a special case for when Type is Object?  In this case, whether it is checked or unchecked, the result would be the same -- mObj can always be successfully cast to type Object.

Comment: @Curds Don't confuse what happens at compile-time with what happens at runtime. The cast `(T) mObj` is different than `(Object) mObj` at compile-time. The first involves a type variable. This is considered an unchecked cast. The `(Object) mObj` is known at compile-time to be always correct because as you implied, `Object` is the root supertype of all reference types. Now at runtime, the first cast is translated to the second, hence no cast exception occurs. The exception occurs later when casting to `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because in the runtime the jvm doesn't know what T is, and it treats it as a `Object`, so the actual cast to the Integer is going on when the generic type is known, so here:
`int i = Test.<Integer>get();`

Answer (score 0):

Generics in java are implemented with erasures. This means that at runtime java has no meaning of the generic types used and uses Object instead.

At runtime "thing" is an Object, and assigning anything to an Object doesn't provoke any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> T get()
```

insists that the result will be of caller type. Thus line

```
int i = Test.<Integer>get();
```

forces Integer to obj to be cases as Integer:

```
thing = (T)mObj;
```

But mObj is an instance of String.

Answer (score 0):

> To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or
>   Object if the type parameters are unbounded.

ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Hence, the code

```
public static <T> T get() {
T thing = null;
try {
    // Expected ClassCastException here
    thing = (T)mObj;
} catch ( ClassCastException e ) {
    System.out.println("This will *not* be printed");
}
return thing;
}
```

at runtime should erase to be

```
public static Object get() {
Object thing = null;
try {
    // Expected ClassCastException here
    thing = (Object)mObj;
} catch ( ClassCastException e ) {
    System.out.println("This will *not* be printed");
}
return thing;
}
```

since T is unbounded. Understand this, then it is easy to explain the output.